# TABLE of age groups

Tags: r

I have different (2 in my example, 85 in my real data) and would like to produce a table of age classes (0-10, 11-20,21-30,31-40 etc.) for each group:

```
 group age
1      1  34
2      1  37
3      1  22
4      1  10
5      1  11
6      1  12
7      1  14
8      2  56
9      2  46
10     2  25
11     2  24
12     2  13
13     2  13
14     2  45
15     2  45
16     2  23
17     2  56
18     2  54
19     2  31
20     2  68
```

I have tried various solutions from the forum:

```
mydf$ageclass<-cut(mydf$age, seq(0,100,10))
```

only works for the entire df and has no possibilty of groups.

```
mydf$ageclass<-Freq(mydf$age, breaks=c(0,20,30,40,50,60,70,80))
```

also only returns a solution for the entire dataframe

I have no way of integrating the "group" into these functions.

Also, both return a column with the age class given as '(30,40]' (meaning upper and lower class bound) and I would like the result to be a table like this:

```
group    0-10    11-20    21-30    31-40
1
2
```

What am I missing? perhaps a for loop? I am new to base R and really would enjoy some pointers as to how to think about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
df$ageclass <- with(mydf, cut(age, seq(0,100,10)))
with(df, table(group, ageclass))

     ageclass
group (0,10] (10,20] (20,30] (30,40] (40,50] (50,60] (60,70] (70,80] (80,90] (90,100]
    1      1       3       1       1       0       0       0       0       0        0
    2      0       2       3       1       3       3       1       0       0        0
```

*Edit*

`cut()` also has a labels argument:

```
df$ageclass <- with(mydf, cut(age, seq(0,100,10), labels = paste0(seq(0,90,10) + 1, "-", seq(0,90,10) + 10)))
with(df, table(group, ageclass))

     ageclass
group 1-10 11-20 21-30 31-40 41-50 51-60 61-70 71-80 81-90 91-100
    1    1     3     1     1     0     0     0     0     0      0
    2    0     2     3     1     3     3     1     0     0      0
```

*Data*

```
mydf <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), age = c(37L, 22L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 14L, 56L, 46L, 25L, 24L, 13L, 13L, 45L, 45L, 23L, 56L, 
54L, 31L, 68L)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: well, not quite what I am looking for, View(df) leads to a data frame with a column per group per age class, I am looking for a data frame with a column per age class and a row per group.

Comment: Change order of the arguments of `table` in that case.